# How to fix "make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: makefile, mingw32

i want to use mingW32_make.exe to compile a C code on command prompt. The error message shows

```
rm -f obj/*.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f obj/*.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:11: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

The makefile is show below

```
CC=gcc
INC_DIR=../include
LIBS=-lregex
ODIR=obj
_OBJ=main.o BVPA.o BVPA-cube.o BVPA-cif.o BVPA-hk.o BVPA-path.o BVPA-math.o BVPA-cmd.o BVPA-gui.o BVPA-vesta.o MT19937AR.o
OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
TARGET=../bin/BVPA_win.exe
CFLAGS=-I$(INC_DIR) -Wall -g

all: $(TARGET)
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o
```

'''

Comment: I'm guessing your shell does not support `rm`...   Try doing `$(info SHELL is $SHELL)` to figure out which shell you're configured for...

Comment: As @HardcoreHenry correctly points out, `cmd.exe` does not understand `rm`. You'll either need to run it under something like `MSYS` or replace `rm -f` with `del /f`, but you'll also then need to replace the slashes of the files you're deleting with backslashes, because `del` doesn't understand forward slashes.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry  I tryied $(info SHELL is $SHELL)， it shows SHELL is HELL.

Comment: @user657267 Thanks for the advice. How to run it under msys? I have add the pacake in MingW.

Comment: Oops, getting my bash and make mixed up:  `$(info SHELL is ${SHELL})`   (makefiles require you add braces to multi-character variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this question is actually simple. There is no obj folder in your current directory so the compiler doesn't know where to add or remove. You can simply **add a obj folder** in your source code directory.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same question and here is the fix.  The reason is given from other's comments:

> Windows does not understand `rm`.

When you run make clean, it will clear out all `.o` files.

clean:

```sh
del *.o
```

Comment: how is it that i can call rm in powershell but not from the makefile?

Comment: @YosefAhab As far as I have understood, the Makefile spawns new shells to execute the tasks and this shell might not be the shell that you started the Makefile with, i.e. Powershell. I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754413/set-powershell-core-as-a-default-gnu-make-shell-on-windows-linux](workaround) solution by Aaron N. Brock to set the Powershell as the executing shell and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same issue, and my solution is below

```
del /f  $(ODIR)\*.o
```

Note that if I use `"$(ODIR)/*.o"` in the makefile, the error would still exist.