# set Powershell core as a default GNU Make shell on windows/linux

Tags: powershell, makefile, gnu-make

In the makefile on Windows.

With the following make version:

```
PS C:\projects> make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for i686-w64-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I have tried to set `SHELL := pwsh` / `COMSPEC := pwsh` and run command without explicit shell specifying:

```
# COMSPEC := pwsh -c
SHELL := pwsh -c

VAR=asdf/asdf

.PHONY: get_var

get_var:
    @Write-Output $(VAR)
```

without success. I've got an error:

```
PS C:\projects\makefile_factory> make -f .\fi.makefile get_var
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, Write-Output asdf/asdf, ...) failed.
make (e=2): ═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы.
.\fi.makefile:10: recipe for target 'get_var' failed
make: *** [get_var] Error 2
```

If shell specified explicitly in the command, it works:

```
# COMSPEC := pwsh -c
# SHELL := pwsh -c

VAR=asdf/asdf

.PHONY: get_var

get_var:
    @pwsh -c Write-Output $(VAR)
```

run:

```
PS C:\projects\makefile_factory> make -f .\fi.makefile get_var
asdf/asdf
```

Also, i've looked into [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell):

> However, on MS-DOS **and MS-Windows the value of SHELL in the
>   environment is used**, since on those systems most users do not set this
>   variable, and therefore it is most likely set specifically to be used
>   by make. On MS-DOS, if the setting of SHELL is not suitable for make,
>   you can set the variable MAKESHELL to the shell that make should use;
>   if set it will be used as the shell instead of the value of SHELL.

So i tried to set environment variable SHELL/MAKESHELL with no result:

```
PS C:\projects\makefile_factory> $env:SHELL
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
PS C:\projects\makefile_factory> $env:MAKESHELL
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
PS C:\projects\makefile_factory> make -f .\fi.makefile get_var
Write-Output asdf/asdf
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, Write-Output asdf/asdf, ...) failed.
make (e=2): ═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы.
.\fi.makefile:9: recipe for target 'get_var' failed
make: *** [get_var] Error 2
```

So, isn't there a way to specify pwsh as a default shell?

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but I doubt it will work to put the options into the same variable as the shell.  I would try using a fully qualified path in the `SHELL` variable, not just `pwsh`, and adding the `-c` option to the `.SHELLFLAGS` variable (note you need at least GNU make 3.82 for this).  If that doesn't work I don't know...

Comment: @MadScientist i'm afraid, make does not react on SHELL variable at all. I receive that output on any value (or even i comment it at all) i.e. it's always use default cmd.exe

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about Windows.  You can try asking on the make-w32@gnu.org mailing list., there might be some people there to help.  Please be sure to include the version of GNU make you're working with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What @raspy says is true, but, I found a *glorious* workaround!

If you take a look at this [if statement right here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/job.c#n2909) you'll notice that if the `shellflags` is set to something besides `-c` or `-ce` it will *always* use the slow option (Which means it will *always* execute through the `SHELL` rather the binary directly! ).  Luckily for us, we can set the `.SHELLFLAGS` directly, take a look at [these docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)

In any event, all that means we need to do is set the `.SHELLFLAGS` to something besides `-c` or `-ce`, for example with powershell we can use `-Command`, tying it all together:

```
SHELL := pwsh
.SHELLFLAGS := -Command

VAR=asdf/asdf

.PHONY: get_var
get_var:
    @Write-Output $(VAR)
```

Or, in my example where I want PowerShell.exe on Windows & the default shell on Linux:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
SHELL := powershell.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command
endif

test.txt:
    echo "hello, world" > test.txt

test:
    rm test.txt
```

Cheers!

Comment: Great finding! I believe that this should be `.SHELLFLAGS` though. And it's only available since 3.82 (which should not be a real limitation in practice).

Comment: Typo fixed :)  & make 3.82 was released _before_ powershell 2.0, so I hope I'm safe for any reasonable case.  But, I feel for those poor souls running powershell 1.0...

Answer (score 4):

This is not as easy as one may think. In general GNU make does not really call shell until it decides it has to do, but rather takes a shortcut and tries to invoke command directly (`exec` or `CreateProcess` depending on the platform).

And how does `make` decide whether the shell is needed? Well, it has a [predefined](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/job.c#n2799) list of keywords to be known by a specific shell. For Windows there is a separate [list](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/job.c#n2774) of keywords specific to `cmd` and a Unixy-shell.

Now, what is a Unixy (a.k.a Bourne-compatible) shell? Well, it's another [predefined](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/job.c#n428) list: `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `rksh`, `zsh`, `ash`, `dash`. Note no `pwsh` here.

So in order to get `make` to actually execute shell, the command must include one of known keywords or characters, otherwise `make` will try to run the command directly, without invoking the shell.

One more thing to remember: when setting up `SHELL`, it has to be either full path or full name of the file to be resolved by searching `PATH` environment variable. Note that PowerShell's executable is `pwsh.exe` not `pwsh` and while the latter works on the command line, it is the command line interpreter that tries different extensions, `make` just simply checks if the file [exists](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/main.c#n977).

Adding up all of the above, I was able to run PowerShell as follows:

```
> Get-Content .\Makefile
SHELL := pwsh.exe

VAR=asdf/asdf

.PHONY: get_var

get_var:
        @&Write-Output $(VAR)
        @$$PSVersionTable
```

Testing with a freshly compiled native Win32 GNU make:

```
> ..\make-4.1\WinRel\gnumake.exe -dr
GNU Make 4.1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
find_and_set_shell() path search set default_shell = C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'get_var'.
 File 'get_var' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'get_var'.
Must remake target 'get_var'.
CreateProcess(NULL,C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe -c "&Write-Output asdf/asdf",...)
Putting child 00B86400 (get_var) PID 12170424 on the chain.
Live child 00B86400 (get_var) PID 12170424
Main thread handle = 0000016C
asdf/asdf
Reaping winning child 00B86400 PID 12170424
CreateProcess(NULL,C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe -c $PSVersionTable,...)
Live child 00B86400 (get_var) PID 12193536

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Reaping winning child 00B86400 PID 12193536
Removing child 00B86400 PID 12193536 from chain.
Successfully remade target file 'get_var'.
```

Comment: Well, that's great! But let me please ask for a question: $$PSVersionTable here all is clear, first dollar is escape character for second one. But what about '&' in Write-Output? Why does make creates subprocess CreateProcess(NULL,Write-Output asdf/asdf,...) if '&' does not specified, and CreateProcess(NULL,C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe -c "&Write-Output asdf/asdf",...) if it does, or CreateProcess(NULL,C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe -c "(Write-Output asdf/asdf)",...) if i take an expression into round brackets? Is there a way to clean that extra characters?

Comment: As I explained earlier, `make` will not invoke shell if it's not convinced that shell is required. It will be convinced if the command includes any of the predefined commands or characters. Both parentheses and ampersand trigger the need for shell, lack of those make `make` believe that `Write-Output` is a binary to run, so it tries to invoke it directly with `CreateProcess`.